# Spring Boot: How to return a file and a text

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I am new to Spring Boot. I want to return a JSON as plain text and, optionally, the JSON file as download (both configurable via a RequestParam).

I managed to get either the plain text (by returning a `ResponseEntity<String>` with a string value as body) or the downloaded file (by returning a `ResponsEntity<Resource>` with a `ByteArrayResource` as body), but not both.

I want to use only one method for this because I do something expensive in this method and I don't want to do this twice.

Does anyone know how to do this? Is there some kind of Spring data structure that allows the packaging of multiple ResponseEntity instances that can be returned by a method with a RequestMapping?

Comment: You should have two endpoints, returning different objects.  String is not a good abstraction in this case.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a good idea to return both file and json at the same time, and difficult.

if method is expensive, can you save the file into a temporary location for download, then  add download url of the file to json, and return to client.

Comment: Thank you. I chose to have separate endpoints for getting the string and for downloading the file. For the file I set up a database where I store the file that was generated during the call of the string-endpoint. The file is downloaded when I call the download-endpoint with the file id.